# Angularjs cannot auto scroll to ng-include section on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When I enter the url, e.g. `localhost:8080/contact`, my `stateProvider` is working correctly but the page doesn't auto scroll to the `ng-include` code section.

**In app.js:**

```
$stateProvider
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',          
            onEnter: function() {
              if ($("#section-1").offset() != null) {
                 $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#section-1").offset().top
                 }, 1000);
              }
            }
        })
        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',         
            onEnter: function() {
              if ($("#section-2").offset() != null) {
                 $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#section-2").offset().top
                 }, 1000);
              }
            }
        })
```

**Then in index.html:**

```
<div class="row" scroll-spy>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li spy="section-1"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
           <li spy="section-2"><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
    .....
    <div class="row">
        <section id="section-1">
            <img src="/images/sg1.jpg" style="width:200; height:700"/>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ng-include src="'/partials/contact.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In contact.html:**

```
<section id="section-2">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="/images/sg2.jpg" style="width:200; height:700"/>
    </div>
</section>
```

The auto scrolling works when i enter the url `'localhost:8080/about'`, but it doesn't work for `'localhost:8080/contact'`. 
The problems seems to be with `ng-include` because there is no problem when I copy the code inside contact.html to index.html. I did some debugging and I realise `$("#section-2").offset()` is null on load when i use `ng-include`. If I click on `'Home'` then `'Contact'` the scrolling works.

How to fix the issue where `$("section-2").offset()` is evaluated as null on page load?

Comment: `$("section-2")` is invalid selector. Should never have jQuery in your routing, use a directive. You are assuming the element exists which it most likely does not in `onEnter`. Look into using `$anchorScroll`

Comment: The dom could not see the anchor as it had to be loaded in. ng-include is loaded in via http which has some latency

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think that @user2891216 is actually using `$("section-2").offset()` within the code sample supplied

Comment: @charlietfl has a great point in that `onEnter` is most likely too soon to attempt to scroll to an element. I ran into a similar issue and had to wait for ui-router's `$viewContentReady` event before attempting to act on elements.

Comment: I tried `$viewContentLoaded` and inside the function I called `$state.go('section-2')` but it still didn't work. Also tried `angular.element(document).ready(function(){...})` but no success. Like what @charlietfl,@Mwayi and @Tony says the ng-include is not loaded so the transition can't occur. Any other methods?

Comment: yes, I already mentioned 2 others . Neither of the approaches you are trying will work. ready and viewContentLoaded don't account for ajax template loading within the view.